# Kinect XBOX 360 in vitual machine

Tags: windows, driver, kinect, hardware, xbox

Good afternoon, I have an Xbox 360 Kinect and want to connect and be recognized on a virtual machine, computer with native Windows I have been able, since I first installed the SDK 1.8 and later connect via USB to the computer and it is recognized, but from a virtual machine only I know me the microphone, while the camera and the engine. (Connect the Kinect to the computer, make sure the USB connection is accessed in the virtual machine, the camera appears blinking led, but devices in the "non-specific" section appear in both "xbox nui camera" and "xbox engine nui ".)

When I try to access any application of Developer Toolkit Browser to start it, I get the message that I have not connected the camera appears.
I'm using both Parallels (Mac) as VirtualBox (Windows) and in both it has been impossible.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Windows documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663795.aspx), only the Kinect for Windows sensor will work on a virtual machine. Kinect for Xbox sensors are not supported.

Kinect for Windows does work within a virtual machine with JDK 1.6 and more.